# Temboo Google Initialize OAuth for Java

Tags: java, oauth, temboo

I am using Temboo to do Google OAuth. I am currently on the OAuth Initialization step (before the Finalize step). I have successfully installed the Temboo SDK.

The following is my initialization code (which was copied straight from Temboo with little to no changes)

```
TembooSession session = new TembooSession("myAccount", "myFirstApp", "someSessionID");

InitializeOAuth initializeOAuthChoreo = new InitializeOAuth(session);

// Get an InputSet object for the choreo
InitializeOAuthInputSet initializeOAuthInputs = initializeOAuthChoreo.newInputSet();

// Set credential to use for execution
initializeOAuthInputs.setCredential("mySavedCredentials");

// Set inputs

// Execute Choreo
InitializeOAuthResultSet initializeOAuthResults = initializeOAuthChoreo.execute(initializeOAuthInputs);
```

Within this code, my `imports` are the following:

```
import com.temboo.Library.Google.OAuth.InitializeOAuth;
import com.temboo.Library.Google.OAuth.InitializeOAuth.InitializeOAuthInputSet;
import com.temboo.Library.Google.OAuth.InitializeOAuth.InitializeOAuthResultSet;
import com.temboo.core.TembooSession
```

That said, Eclipse is screaming at me saying that my `.setCredential("..");` line is incorrect:

I have the following errors:

1. `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`
2. `Syntax error on token "mySavedCredentials", delete this token`

I tried using different imports, such as the non-Google-OAuth import (the OAuth2 one), thinking I was using a wrong import and thus the lack of the `.setCredentials()` method, but that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for Temboo.

This error could be caused if you are using an older version of our Java SDK. You can download the latest SDK here: https://temboo.com/download.

Hopefully this helps. Feel free to contact us at https://temboo.com/support if you have any questions.